# Limit number of instances of Azure Function Apps v2

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, servicebus

I need to have only one instance of an Azure Function App in place and put the following json code in `host.json`.

But when a function gets triggered by a `servicebus queue`, I can clearly see in `Live Metrics Stream` in Application Insights that several servers get provisioned to serve the load. What am I missing to limit the running servers to only one?

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT": 1,
  "maxConcurrentCalls": 2,
  "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "prefetchCount": 1,
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "maxConcurrentCalls": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to do that?
Remember that each instance can process multiple messages at the same time, so 1 instance does not means one message at at time

Anyways, you can go to your app settings and add the following:
`WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT = 1`

[image: Azure Functions settings]

Comment: I assume from the config in the question that they're also planning to limit the per-instance concurrency of the trigger, which would be why they would want to do that.

Comment: The medium that the Functions are working with, can not handle many concurrent connections. It does not have to be only one connection but more than a few, disrupts the process. But as @MarkXA mentioned, this setting is not reliable. After putting it in application-settings with the value 2, I still see like 6 active servers sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

`WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` is an application setting, not a `host.json` setting. I would also point out that it's somewhat less than 100% reliable, so if you need a hard guarantee of only 1 instance then you should use either a Premium plan or a standard App Service plan rather than a Consumption plan.